# suggestion for good online source according to Syllabus

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science-model

[image]

Hi, are there some online courses e.g. some classes in Coursera?

I have difficulty in following the professor's teaching because I have a weak statistics background. I want to catch up by reading some online complementary resource!

Thank you!

Comment: ML is a vast domain and there are plenty of resources available, so try to identify the precise area that you need and find a resource which corresponds to your level. for instance if basic statistics is the issue, there are plenty of books providing a gentle introduction to stats (and probably online courses as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good deal of the topics, excluding the more advanced ones like autoencoders or manifold learning, can be learned in the excellent course of andrew ng https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning
There's also https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning?utm_source=deeplearningai&utm_medium=institutions&utm_campaign=WebsiteCoursesDLSBottomButton that goes deeper into aspects of deep learning
For generative models I don't have specific recommendations...